# Inheritance Networks in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to draw the inheritance network for a number of classes. I want to number each class in the drawing showing in what order the class objects are searched for attributes (1=first, 2=second, etc.) in object g = G(). Here is what am trying to simulate:

```
class A : pass
class C : pass
class B(A,C) : pass
class D(A) : pass
class E(B,C) : pass
class F(C) : pass
class G(D,E,F): pass
```

I went and made the following network. Is there any way to improve upon it, and have I done it this correctly?

[image: inheritance diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram is almost right as far as showing the inheritance relationships between the classes you've shown. The arrow from `B` to `E` should run in the other direction, but everything else is right.

As for numbering the classes in the diagram based on the order they'll be checked in a lookup on an instance of class `G`, I suggest calling `G.mro()`. This will give you a list of the classes in the order they'll be searched.

Here's what I get for your example classes:

```
[<class '__main__.G'>,
 <class '__main__.D'>,
 <class '__main__.E'>,
 <class '__main__.B'>,
 <class '__main__.A'>,
 <class '__main__.F'>,
 <class '__main__.C'>,
 <class 'object'>]
```

If you want to understand how this order is found, you should read up about the [C3 linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) algorithm that Python uses. A good place to start is [this article](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) written about the new algorithm when it was introduced in Python 2.3.

Comment: @Blckknght- Thanks. So the order of checking would be:                        `G[1], D[2], E[3], B[4], A[5], F[6], C[7]`.